# Error bibtex with jabref

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, jabref

I've made a little bib file with jabref. When i compile it with Texmaker (F11) I obtain:

```
**This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9) The top-level auxiliary file:   
prueba.aux The style file: apalike.bst Database file #1: bibio.bib Warning--I 
didn't find a database entry for "S�nchez" (There was 1 warning)**
```

The bib file is:

```
% This file was created with JabRef 2.9.2.
%  Encoding: Cp1252

@BOOK{Sanchez,
  title = {Problemas Resueltos De M\'{e}todos Num\'{e}ricos},
  publisher = {Thomson},
  year = {2006},
  author = {Alicia Cordero Barbero and Jos\'{e} Luis Hueso Pagoaga and Eulalia
    Mart\'{i}nez Molada and Juan Ram\'{o}n Torregrosa S\'{a}nchez},
  pages = {37-69},
  edition = {1},
  isbn = {84-9732-409-9},
  url = {www.paraninfo.es}
}

@BOOK{Cabezas,
  title = {M\'{e}todos Num\'{e}ricos Teor\'{i}a, problemas y pr\'{a}cticas con
    MATLAB},
  publisher = {Pir\'{a}mide},
  year = {2007},
  author = {Juan Antonio Infante Del R\'{i}o and Jos\'{e} Mar\'{i}a Rey Cabezas},
  pages = {435-483},
  edition = {3},
  isbn = {978-84-368-2090-4}
}
```

In the pdf i don't see Sanchez entry and i see Cabezas entry

Comment: What does the argument of your `\cite` command look like? Is it maybe `\cite{Sánchez}`? What happens if you change it to `\cite{Sanchez}`?

Comment: Oh, thanks!!! must i always add \cite in my latex documents or is there any way to add bibligraphy without add \cite ?

Comment: Regarding the question in your follow-up comment: If all entries in your bib file should show up in the References section regardless of whether they're cited explicitly or not, issuing the command `\nocite{*}` will let you achieve that. If you want to have some selected entries show up in the References while not citing them explicitly, use `\nocite{...}` with the appropriate keys. Of course, entries that are explicitly `\cite`ed in the body of the text will show up in the References automatically.

Answer (score 3):

The warning you have says

```
I didn't find a database entry for "S�nchez"
```

which looks very much like an accented character in the key (`Sánchez`). That's not the same as the entry you show in your database (`Sanchez`), so unsurprisingly it's not matched.

I'd caution against using accents in keys in general. The 'classic' BibTeX program is 7-bit and while BibTeX8 expands to 8-bit it still doesn't support accents *in keys*. The BibTeX format essentially defines keys as strictly ASCII, and both the 'classical' tools and alternative parsers may break with other characters in keys.